# iOS 11 Top Item Check For UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, xcode9

I was using this control to reach UINavigation bar and items of it.

```
if ([self.searchBar.superview isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]]) { 
       navigationItem = ((UINavigationBar *) self.searchBar.superview).topItem;
  }
```

But when i use iOS 11 simulator and xCode 9 it doesnt work.

If i debug with lower versions of simulator like iOS 8.2 and print

```
po self.searchBar.superView
```

it prints "UINavigationBar" but when i did same on iOS 11 it print "_UINavigationBarContentView".

How should i change my code for iOS 11 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
if (@available (iOS 11.0, *)) {
  if ([self.searchBar.superview isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]]) {
    navigationItem = ((UINavigationBar *) self.searchBar.superview).topItem;
  }
} else {
  if ([self.searchBar.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]]) {
    navigationItem = ((UINavigationBar *) self.searchBar.superview.superview).topItem;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but as i said 'self.searchBar.superview' is UINavigationBarContentView on iOS 11 so 'if ([self.searchBar.superview isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])' control returns nil

Comment: also i think  " if (@available (iOS 11.0, *)) { } " is better way to check version :)

Comment: Agree my friend :). I will edit my answer with your suggestion for everyone else who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You use following code.
may be you did not add below line then you should get 'nil' response.
navigationItem.searchController = searchController

There's a new searchController property on navigationItem in iOS 11.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller

iOS 11 is let’s begin from the large title. Almost all projects contain a navigation controller. In order to setup the large title in the navigation bar of this controller, a new property prefersLargeTitles should be set to true.

Use like this...

For example, the following line can be added to a viewDidLoad function of a view controller:

In Swift Code:-

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
     navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
}
```

Objective C Code:-

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.searchController = searchController;
} else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
     navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
}
```